# How to create vertical line which shows y1, y2 coordinates on the chart [c#]?

Tags: c#, charts, coordinates

I'm looking for sample code which show red vertical line, and get y1,y2 coordinates from chart, when we have for example 2 series, and the red vertical line is on the series (I showed it in the following picture) ?

I found this code here on the stackoverflow (shows red vertical line, and I cen get x value, but I don't know how to get y value):

```
private void chart1_MouseWhatever(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    Point chartLocationOnForm = chart1.FindForm().PointToClient(chart1.Parent.PointToScreen(chart1.Location));                

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(new PointF(e.X - chartLocationOnForm.X, e.Y -     chartLocationOnForm.Y), true);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(new PointF(e.X - chartLocationOnForm.X, e.Y - chartLocationOnForm.Y), true);

    double x = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Position;
    double y = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Position;
}
```

I found too this code (which shows crosshair and back x,y coordinates, but I don't need horizontal line, because program slow down):

```
private void OnChartMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceChart = sender as Chart;
    HitTestResult result = sourceChart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    ChartArea chartAreas = sourceChart.ChartAreas[0];

    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)  
    {
        chartAreas.CursorX.Position = chartAreas.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        chartAreas.CursorY.Position = chartAreas.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
    }
}
```

Is any simple way to do modifications which shows for example y1, y2 coordinates? Maybe someone know how to do this or could gave me any useful tips? I'm looking a lot, but I found only x,y coordinates example.

[image]

Comment: I would add one or Two LineAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

`Axis.PixelPositionToValue` should do what you want, except it says it can only be invoked from Paint methods

Comment: Kristopher maybe You have any idea, how to compare and display value y1 and y2 when I moved this red vertical line? I used this Axis.PixelPositionToValue, but I dont have idea, what to do next to compare and display both y1 and y2 value in the same time.